# Identity in front-end

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, security, asp.net-identity, backend

can I handle identity in the front end as auth guard in angular instead of creating identity management on the server-side ?
auth guard can handle anything about identity instead of server-side in small projects for example if I have student and teacher role, based on the type of user from response I can validate user permissions for each user

Comment: yes you can do that. But you can't trust the frontend. Any student could "pretend" to be a teacher if you don't have server side security.

Comment: No he couldn't because based on login ,   the server detect if he is a student or teacher by claims, he can only register as a teacher and in this case he will has a teacher account

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, storing the data to the client-side is not a good choice. This will make a lot of issue.

1. Not security. The client side could modify the teacher or student role just by using F12 develop tool or else. Since all the data is stored at the client-side. Then you could also modify the request to act teacher or student.
2. Not keep the data same, if you modify some role, the client-side will not receive the update for its side. He will still use the old data.

Comment: How, I store this information about roles as token in local storage, so it impossible to decode the token and modify anything,

Comment: How you generate the token? Do you use client-side codes? If you use client-side codes that means client-side user could modify it.

Comment: No, it generates by the server

Comment: So your client will decode the token and identity the role? The decode codes will still be seen at the client side.

Comment: but still, if he decoded the token and modify it then resend it to the server, the server will respond with 401 because the token wouldn't be a match

Comment: If you generate the token at server side and check the token at server-side that will be find, there is no security issue.